# Splitting letter in a string to separate row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have days(working days for the school) field in `school_calendar` table as given below

```
select days from school_calendars where id=1;
```

returns MTWHF as result

I want the output as followed

```
+---------+  
  Days
+---------+
|    M    |
|    T    |
|    W    |
|    H    |
|    F    |
+---------+
```

Comment: I formatted your tables. But guess what you can do it yourself too :D Just indent it with the **{ }** brackets in the code editor. Mark your whole code / tables and indent them :)

Comment: See this for a guide to a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: How long is the max length of the string?

Comment: @kickstart -->varchar(7)

Answer (score 0):

Doing it for a string up to 1000 characters long:-

```
SELECT SUBSTR(days, aNum, 1) AS aDay
FROM school_calendars 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + units.aCnt + tens.aCnt * 10 + hundreds.aCnt * 100 AS aNum
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units.
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens,
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds
) sub0
ON sub0.aNum <= LENGTH(days)
WHERE id=1;
```

For a short varchar(7) that can be simplified to

```
SELECT SUBSTR(days, aNum, 1) AS aDay
FROM school_calendars 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS aNum UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 
) sub0
ON sub0.aNum <= LENGTH(days)
WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: I get the following error :  Unknown column 'sub0' in 'on clause'.while executing second query

Comment: I have just tried it and it does work (I did do a minor edit just after I first posted it - you might have missed that change)

Comment: SELECT SUBSTR(days, aNum, 1) AS aDay
FROM school_calendars 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 AS aNum UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
) sub0
ON sub0.aNum <= LENGTH(days)
WHERE id = 1;